# Usage of "take somebody to somewhere"

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-usage

As I understand, the phrase above can mean to invite someone to somewhere, then to give someone a lift/to provide transportation for someone. Do I get it right? As I am not a native speaker of English and do not live in an English-speaking country, I have questions about how often this phrase is used in this sense? Perhaps it is not so usual to say that this way when you give invitation tickets to someone and offer to give a ride at the same time?  Is this phrase rarely (often) said when referring to children or inanimate nouns like books, tablets, etc. or the handicapped?

The example below:

> Mr Hopewell, Director of Client Relations Department, was given four invitation cards to the charity party "Save Panda", and he took three colleagues to this "green" event.

Comment: *Take* can mean *invite and accompany as a companion or guest*, and it can mean *give transport to*. Context determines whether it means one, the other or both.

Answer (score 1):

Take, in the sense you are describing, means to accompany someone to a certain location. That's about as far as it goes. When you "take" someone somewhere, you don't necessarily need to invite them.

"Take" is a fairly common verb in the English language. It's used very often in informal speech. Examples:

*"I will **take** you to your room now."*

*He looked around and realized Joel had **taken** all of his friends to the fair.*

Answer (score 0):

Also, yes it can be used for inanimate objects: you can say 'I took a book to the lecture' or 'I took some flowers to my mother' - or, of course, 'I took my mother some flowers'. In this sense it is very nearly a synonym of 'give' - despite 'give' and 'take' often being listed as synonyms. I have seen some very good (but non-native) English speakers trip over this.